Reporting sentences
Reported speech

She said that she's going there

She said that she was going there


Both sentences are fine. 1 is used when something is still  true. 2 might still be true or not. Can we do the same way with these examples if something is still true?

I heard she is angry

I saw it works

I saw she is beautiful



You don't need that: She said she's going there. I saw how it works. BUT I saw that it works. 3 and 5 can be is or was, depending on whether the condition is still true in the present. But over all, your sentences need some work.

You're right about the possible meanings of sentences 1 and 2.
It works the same for 3, because it's reported speech.
Sentences 4 and 5, however, are not reported speech. "See" describes an observation, and does not report what someone else said. Those two sentences are reduced relative clauses:


I saw that it works.
I saw that she is beautiful.


This rule only applies to reported speech, not relative clauses, reduced or otherwise.
